# What "practical" physics problems do you "actually" face?

Tags: discussion, site-faq

The FAQ states:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

This bit is highlighted.

This sentence has an obvious meaning, which is wrong. Almost none of the questions here deal with [practical](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/practical) questions about [actual](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/actual) problems that the OP faced. Rather, this bit is boilerplate text common to various stackexchange sites. On many of those sites the obvious meaning may well be appropriate, but here we should say something else.

Am I correct? If so, what should it really say?

Comment: What if you are a graduate student studying something. Then an actual problem that you face may be anything you don't understand and couldn't figure out. No?

Comment: @MBN: would this mean that some questions are only valid if the person asking them is actually a graduate student? Also, "practical".

Comment: Grad. student is just an example of a person with an actual problem that he faces. Obviously it doesn't matter whether the person is a student or not, as long as he asks a questions about an actual problem he faces.

Comment: I don't know what you understand by practical, but to me that part is fine too. It is practical to learn various things, so asking a question about it makes it a practical question. For example how to solve a certain type of problems in say quantum field theory.

Comment: @MBN: So you're saying "actual" and "practical" are fine as they are, because what they really mean is something like "anything you don't understand and couldn't figure out"? Perhaps make that an answer?

Comment: It is not what I said.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I'm not sure what you're saying. Feel free to elaborate on your view in an answer.

Comment: I don't understand what is unclear! To me practical doesn't necessarily mean something like "how to paint my fence" or "how to calculate grocery bills". For a physicist, even a grad. student, a practical could (and does) mean something else, a question here, which is considered excellent, could easily be a practical question. Why don't you say what you understand by practical and why it bothers you in the sentence above?

Comment: Very well. I amended the question to include links. While "practical" can be interpreted in an unusual way, surely the obvious meaning is more or less the opposite of theoretical. See also dmckee's showcase below.

Answer (score 12):

I think my answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164436/is-there-a-rule-of-thumb-for-objective-questions-asked-out-of-curiosity/164452#164452) says it all (and some of the other answers as well).

Basically, it's a rule that makes sense for the SOFU trilogy, and not for science sites.

Comment: In that answer you suggest: "You should only ask answerable questions that will be useful to others". This sounds sensible to me.

Answer (score 7):

[Of](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28935/amount-flow-rate-of-n2-needed-to-cool-substrate) 
course, 
[us](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22552/strategies-against-50hz-mains-hum-on-detector-signals) 
experimental
[types](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56074/laymans-method-to-sharpen-a-wire-stm-tip) 
can
[have](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/34193/how-are-the-masses-of-unstable-elementary-particles-measured) 
[practical](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47304/experimental-technique-for-measuring-temperature-of-an-ant) 
physics 
[questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38859/how-to-properly-bake-a-ultra-high-vacuum-chamber).

[That's](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52105/ways-to-create-controlled-small-bubbles-in-water-within-plastic-tubing)
because
[we're](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44784/how-to-determine-whether-a-large-container-is-air-tight)
practical
[people](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/physical-vapor-deposition-of-sio2).

[Take](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15469/how-to-guess-the-correct-fitting-function-to-some-data) 
that 
[you](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13408/fitting-to-a-high-density-scatter-plot)
smarty-pants
[people](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52805/improvements-on-a-makeshift-dessicator)!

Comment: Shame that the career fair never mentioned [sticking tiny thermometers up the posteriors of ants](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47304), I would surely have become an "experimental type"!

Comment: It is hard to read this without mentally emphasizing on the links. It is impossible to read this without laughing.